# The Tkinter Listbox is not displaying as expected

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Encountered with one problem. Making "modification" of default tk Listbox, adding Scrollbar widget to it. I made class, added Scrollbar, and tried to test it. I didn't saw Listbox, only Scrollbar. But if I remove Scrollbar, it's appear.

Here's code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ScrollableListbox(tk.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)

        self.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.yview)

        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")
    scrollable_listbox = ScrollableListbox(root)
    scrollable_listbox.pack()

    for i in range(1, 21):
        scrollable_listbox.insert("end", f"Item {i}")

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change this line: **self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master)**, because your master is set to be the listbox itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you made the listbox the master of the scrollbar. When you  pack the scrollbar in the listbox the listbox will shrink to fit it. The listbox is there, it's just that it's only a couple pixels wider and taller than the scrollbar. This is the normal behavior of `pack`.

You shouldn't be putting the scrollbar inside the listbox. If you want to make it appear to be inside, the best practice is to create a frame, then put the listbox and scrollbar inside that frame. If you set the borderwidth of the listbox to zero, and set the borderwidth of the frame to 1 or 2, it will appear that the scrollbar is inside the listbox.